# How do I render a list of elements with Phoenix.HTML

Tags: phoenix-framework

I'm trying to render a list of elements in a View file. I can render them I wrap them in another element like:

```
iex(9)> span1 = content_tag(:span, "test1")
{:safe, [60, "span", [], 62, "test1", 60, 47, "span", 62]}
iex(10)> span2 = content_tag(:span, "test2")
{:safe, [60, "span", [], 62, "test2", 60, 47, "span", 62]}
iex(11)> content_tag(:div, [span1, span2]) |> safe_to_string
"<div><span>test1</span><span>test2</span></div>"
```

However, how can I render just the two spans? The following doesn't work.

```
iex(12)> [span1, span2] |> safe_to_string
** (FunctionClauseError) no function clause matching in Phoenix.HTML.safe_to_string/1
    (phoenix_html) lib/phoenix_html.ex:160: Phoenix.HTML.safe_to_string([safe: [60, "span", [], 62, "test1", 60, 47, "span", 62], safe: [60, "span", [], 62, "test2", 60, 47, "span", 62]])
iex(12)>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to pass the list to `Phoenix.HTML.html_escape/1` first (`Phoenix.HTML.Tag.content_tag/2` does the same internally):

```
iex(1)> import Phoenix.{HTML, HTML.Tag}
[Phoenix.HTML, Phoenix.HTML.Tag]
iex(2)> span1 = content_tag(:span, "test1")
{:safe, [60, "span", [], 62, "test1", 60, 47, "span", 62]}
iex(3)> span2 = content_tag(:span, "test2")
{:safe, [60, "span", [], 62, "test2", 60, 47, "span", 62]}
iex(4)> html_escape([span1, span2])
{:safe,
 [[60, "span", [], 62, "test1", 60, 47, "span", 62],
  [60, "span", [], 62, "test2", 60, 47, "span", 62]]}
iex(5)> html_escape([span1, span2]) |> safe_to_string
"<span>test1</span><span>test2</span>"
```